# How to make the animation look the same on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, css-animations

https://that-project.netlify.app/

On Chrome it looks good.
But on Safari it's full of lag and delay.(first animation wonderful brilliant etc)
I used something like this to change the word value.
But if I remove them it works good, from what I say( i don't have safari so I used browserstack)

Any solution? Please..

```
const time = 2500;
  const delay = 6000;
  const time3 = 12000;
  const time4 = 4500;

sleep(time * 1 + delay).then(() => {elements[0].innerHTML = "Enjoyable";});
sleep(time + (time3 * 1) + delay).then(() => {elements[0].innerHTML = "Wonderful";});
sleep(time + (time3 * 2) + delay).then(() => {elements[0].innerHTML = "Enjoyable";});
sleep(time + (time3 * 3) + delay).then(() => {elements[0].innerHTML = "Wonderful";});


sleep(time4 * 1 + delay).then(() => {elements[1].innerHTML = "Outstanding";});
sleep(time4 + (time3 * 1 + delay)).then(() => {elements[1].innerHTML = "Brilliant";});
sleep(time4 + (time3 * 2) + delay).then(() => {elements[1].innerHTML = "Outstanding";});
sleep(time4 + (time3 * 3) + delay).then(() => {elements[1].innerHTML = "Brilliant";});
sleep(time4 + (time3 * 4) + delay).then(() => {elements[1].innerHTML = "Outstanding";});
```

Comment: what is `sleep` ?

Comment: Works for me on Safari on IOS 14.

Comment: @ManosKounelakis It's a function                                                                                               function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

Comment: @AHaworth Yeah on some devices it works on others not. For example, on iPhone Xs, it looks laggy and ugly while on iPhone 11 looks smooth and clean.